# hide other divs what doesnt contain select option data attribute

Tags: jquery

How I can hide other divs what doesnt contain select option data attribute value?

```
<div class="booked-serviceSwitcher calendar">
    <p>
        <i class="booked-icon booked-icon-calendar"></i>
        <select class="booked_calendar_chooser" id="change_service_booked">
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP">Party</option>
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO">School</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="booked-appt-list shown" style="display: block;">
    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;14:45 – 16:45</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Exclusive studio - #KO" data-timeslot="1445-1645" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">14:45 – 16:45</span><span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;17:15 – 19:15</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Prime studio - #SP" data-timeslot="1715-1915" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">17:15 – 19:15</span>
                <span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if I select `Party` and its prefix is `SP` then it should show only `SP` divs and hide others.

My jquery code what I've tried to achive this:

```
let title = $("#change_service_booked option").attr("data-prefix");
let textt = $(".booked-appt-list > .timeslot > .timeslot-time .timeslot-title").text();

if (title.indexOf(textt) >= 0) {
    $(".booked-appt-list > .timeslot > .timeslot-time .timeslot-title:contains(textt)").parent('.timeslot-time').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have one solution. I added a new class to both divs named `dataIdTarget` that will help hide the divs that you dont want to show, and i added a `data atribute` with the ''id'' KO, and SP, you can see they are `data-idTarget`. I made a function `showHide` that is called when the page loads (document ready) and when someone chooses a new option it will too trigger the function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  hideShow();
});

$('#change_service_booked').change(function(){
  hideShow();
});

function hideShow()
{
  var selected = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').data('prefix');
  $('.dataIdTarget').hide();
  $('*[data-idTarget="'+selected+'"]').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="booked-serviceSwitcher calendar">
  <p>
    <i class="booked-icon booked-icon-calendar"></i>
    <select class="booked_calendar_chooser" id="change_service_booked">
      <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP">Party</option>
      <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO">School</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="booked-appt-list shown" style="display: block;">
  <div data-idTarget="KO" class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title dataIdTarget ">
    <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
    <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;14:45 – 16:45</span>
    </span>
    <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Exclusive studio - #KO" data-timeslot="1445-1645" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
    <span class="button-timeslot">14:45 – 16:45</span><span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div data-idTarget="SP" class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title dataIdTarget ">
    <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
    <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;17:15 – 19:15</span>
    </span>
    <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Prime studio - #SP" data-timeslot="1715-1915" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
    <span class="button-timeslot">17:15 – 19:15</span>
    <span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic

- Trigger the change event.
- Get the `data-prefix` attribute of selected option.
- Hide the parent with selector.

In order to hide the whole element with that specific content, you have to target the parent having class `timeslot`. This is parent of parent. Or parent of index 1. This can be selected either one of the way below.

**Option 1**

```
$(`.booked-appt-list > .timeslot > .timeslot-time .timeslot-title:not(:contains(${selectedPrefix}))`).parent().parent()
```

**Option 2**

```
$(`.booked-appt-list > .timeslot > .timeslot-time .timeslot-title:contains(${selectedPrefix})`).parents().eq(1)
```

Here I'm going for the second option.

Im `show`ing the `div`s that contain the text with `data-prefix` of selected option and `hide`ing the `div`s that doesnot contain the `data-prefix` of selected option

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$("#change_service_booked").change((e) => {
  const selectedPrefix = $("#change_service_booked").find(":selected").attr("data-prefix");
  $(`.booked-appt-list > .timeslot > .timeslot-time .timeslot-title:contains(${selectedPrefix})`).parents().eq(1).show();
  $(`.booked-appt-list > .timeslot > .timeslot-time .timeslot-title:not(:contains(${selectedPrefix}))`).parents().eq(1).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="booked-serviceSwitcher calendar">
  <p>
    <i class="booked-icon booked-icon-calendar"></i>
    <select class="booked_calendar_chooser" id="change_service_booked">
      <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP">Party</option>
      <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO">School</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="booked-appt-list shown" style="display: block;">
  <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
    <span class="timeslot-time">
      <span class="timeslot-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
      <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;14:45 – 16:45</span>
    </span>
    <span class="timeslot-people">
      <button data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Exclusive studio - #KO" data-timeslot="1445-1645"
        data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
        <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
        <span class="button-timeslot">14:45 – 16:45</span><span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
    <span class="timeslot-time">
      <span class="timeslot-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
      <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;17:15 – 19:15</span>
    </span>
    <span class="timeslot-people">
      <button data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Prime studio - #SP" data-timeslot="1715-1915" data-date="2021-09-20"
        class="new-appt button">
        <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
        <span class="button-timeslot">17:15 – 19:15</span>
        <span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```